# Individual column search on top rather than bottom in angular datatable

Tags: javascript, css, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using this library https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome for my angular 7 project I have implemented the code as given the the example as it is, https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/individual-column-filtering.

It is working perfectly fine , but only problem is the position of the search columns ,
I want the search columns in header after the columns names,
I tried converting the `tfoot` to `thead` but it's not working.

I found some examples like http://live.datatables.net/cutucahi/1/edit, but the exmaple is replacing the header columns with the search box which i dont want

Answer (score 3):

Try below example

```js
initComplete: function ()
{
  var r = $('#MyDataTable tfoot tr');
  r.find('th').each(function(){
    $(this).css('padding', 8);
  });
  $('#MyDataTable thead').append(r);
  $('#search_0').css('text-align', 'center');
},
```

If not check solution in following link

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
  -- In Comments section. Multiple solutions are given.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the table header html do this

```
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="test">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr> 
    </thead>
```

If you notice i have added one more `tr` and created the same headers

After this in js file change the element selector from

```
$('#example thead th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder='+title+' />' );
} );
```

to

```
$('#example thead #test th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder='+title+' />' );
} );
```

This will solve your problem.

please check the link i am not sure if it gets loaded properly

[check it](http://live.datatables.net/sitirosi/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that all `input[type=text]`(Search Box) below all the column names respectively you must **append** it to their respective tr's
Change your js to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).append( '<br><input type="text" placeholder='+title+' />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      scrollX: true
    });

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Click here to see the [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/r47hf2ep/)