# How to add a row above header datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to create a table with datatables and DOTNET MVC. How Can I create a row above the header that contains every select tag each column so I can filter the data? it looks like the image below

```cs
 <table id="orderTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                                <th>Customer </th>
                                <th>Order date</th>
                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                <th>Dish</th>
                                <th>Delivery Address</th>
                                <th>Message</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@order.OrderId</td>
                                    <td>@order.CustomerName</td>
                                    <td>@order.OrderDate</td>
                                    <td>@order.PhoneNumber</td>
                                    <td>@order.Dish</td>
                                    <td>@order.DeliveryAddress</td>
                                    <td>@order.Message</td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                            </tbody>


                        </table>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Individual column search on top rather than bottom in angular datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61612623/individual-column-search-on-top-rather-than-bottom-in-angular-datatable)

Comment: Also, you can take a look at this example - specifically, look at the solutions provided in the "Comments" tab: [Individual column searching](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html).